# Use DbCommandInterceptor from AddDbContext to implement a Database Activity Indicator

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

With using the DbCommandInterceptor I can monitor all database requests and therefore this would be a good place to implement a database activity indicator and show this in my pages (i. e. spinner).

The current implementation is very simple, and I can track all activities in my DbCommandInterceptor class.

CommandInterceptor.cs

```
public class CommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor {}
public override InterceptionResult<int> NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("NonQueryExecuting");
    return base.NonQueryExecuting(command, eventData, result);
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            .AddInterceptors(new CommandInterceptor()));
}
```

How can I use the DbCommandInterceptor in my pages?

Comment: Just like any other service you want to use in a controller or page....you register it as a service and allow dependency injection to inject it? Have you tried that? Did it work?

Comment: How can I achieve this when I can't access the service inside DbContext in ConfigureServices?

Comment: Why do you need to access the service from your DbContext? It's an interceptor - right? When the interceptor is registered properly with the DbContext, it will intercept the commands - right? So you don't need to have the service inside of the DbContext itself. What you need is a shared storage area where the interceptor can store current jobs, and that storage should be accessible from your controllers and/or pages. You can decide whether you want that store to be in memory, or in your database, or a separate database, or some sort of caching location like Redis.

Comment: I was trying to create an additional service and inject this into my CommandInterceptor which then could be injected and used in my pages but failed.
Is a shared storage the only way to do this?

Comment: How else do you want to communicate between two different parts of your application that exist in different contexts?

Comment: Ok, it seems to be more complicated than I thought. What is the easiest solution to do this in memory? I have no idea where to start. Could you give me a hint or short example?

Comment: Create an object that gets injected into both objects that has a threadsafe collection object. The interceptor would add to that object, the pages/controllers could read from it.

Comment: This is what I already mentioned before.

> I was trying to create an additional service and inject this into my CommandInterceptor which then could be injected and used in my pages but failed.

How can I inject an object into DbCommandInterceptor?